# Reverse lookup in MATLAB cell array of indices

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have hit a brick wall trying to solve this:

Given a 5x1 cell array of vectors of indices to an array of n elements I need to find the reverse mapping.

What I have is the relation "In group 2, there are elements 15, 16, 17,...."
What I want to have is "Element 15 is member of group 2,4,5."

This is the structure of my cell array

```
myCellArray  = 

[1x228 double]
[1x79  double]
[1x136 double]
[1x93  double]
[1x81  double]
```

This is part of the contents of my index vector

```
myCellArray{2}(1:5) =

    15    16    17    18    19
```

What I want is a cell array of n cells containing the indices of group membership for each element.

help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `cellfun` and `arrayfun`. First create a cell array:

```
>> mycellarray = { [1 2], [4 5], [3 4], [1 2 3 4 5] };
```

To get the elements of the cell array that contain a particular number (say 1) you can use `cellfun`:

```
>> find( cellfun(@(s)ismember(1, s), mycellarray) )
ans =
    1   4
```

Which tells you that 1 is in the 1st and 4th elements of `mycellarray`. Now you can just map this over the list of all possible indexes using `arrayfun`. The arrays that are produced might be of different length, so we need to set `'UniformOutput'` to `false`.

```
>> n = 5;
>> result = arrayfun(@(i)find(cellfun(@(s)ismember(i,s), mycellarray)), 1:n, ...
                     'UniformOutput', false);
```

The elements are the index vectors that you want --

```
>> result{1}
ans =
     1     4    # since 1 is in the 1st and 4th array
>> result{3}
ans =
     3     4    # since 3 is in the 3rd and 4th array
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you have to use cell arrays to save space?

Otherwise can you change your current matrix to an MxN normal matrix where N is n as you have defined and M is the number of groups. And then just pad the end of each row with zeros. So it holds the same information but it makes your reverse query easy to do using `find`.

so if `n = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]`

and we have 3 groups such that group 1 is `[1 4 5]`, group 2 is `[3]` and group 3 is `[1 2 6 7]` your current matrix would be

```
M = 3; N = numel(n);

m = zeros(M,N);
m(1, 1:3) = [1 4 5];
m(2, 1) = 3;
m(3, 1:4) = [1 2 6 7];
```

now you want to know which group does the number `i` belong to. It's as simple as (updated based on Chris Taylor's observation)

```
find(any(m == i, 2))
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work. For example, `find(m == 2)` returns `6`. To get the groups containing `i` I think you need to write `find(any(m == i, 2))` instead.

Comment: Well spotted, I didn't test for the case of only one result I guess. Will edit now.